# Disable the message " these files are on a digital audio player" in na

Tags: nautilus, mount, android

When I mount my Android phone with USB cable to Ubuntu 12.04 I get "these files are on a digital audio player" and open with rhythmbox in nautilus.This means that I am not able to see any file within my android.

Is it possible to disable the recognition of digital audio player and just list all files as usual?

EDIT

I found the issue. The issue was completely different than I thought. I actually have a Samsung galaxy S2. If you plug in the phone via USB you can see the device but you are not able to see any files.

But if you follow this guide, you will be able to see all files;

http://www.the-computer-geek.co.uk/?p=435

Thanks everybody for your efforts.

Comment: The files _should_ be listed as usual (in addition to the "these files..." bar at the top)

Comment: I thought so also but I am not able to see any file. Probably it is something else that cause this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each USB device presents itself to the operating system with a [device class code](http://www.usb.org/developers/defined_class). This determines what kind of device is plugged into your computer and thus enables your OS to  initiate class dependent actions.

It is likely that your phone sends the device class identifier `01h Audio` to Ubuntu. Therefore seemingly correct Rhythmbox is opened as we believed it was an mp3-player.

Unless you are able to change this code from settings on your phone the easiest approach to avoid starting a media player is to [turn off the default behaviour](https://askubuntu.com/a/140890/3940) on what to do when a "audio"-USB-device is plugged in.

A more basic approach would be to define a [udev rule](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=168221) for a given device.

We have no experience with this software, but you may also be able to change the USB mode of a flip-flop device with the help of [usb-modeswitch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/usb-modeswitch) [image: Install usb-modeswitch].

See the [instructions on the support page](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/) for details on usage.

Comment: Yes I thought it was something like that. Thanks for you help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may disable this behaviour by going to system settings, details, removable media and select the 'do nothing' option.